# Setting up a cluster of Neo4j instances

Tags: azure, neo4j

We have followed the instructions on ["Alternative setup: Creating a local cluster for testing"](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html#ha-local-cluster) section which shows one how to set up a cluster of neo4j instances.

but when we try hit `http://127.0.0.1:7474` or `http://127.0.0.1:7475` it returns empty? why would this happen if we followed the instructions step by step?

We are running neo4j in two separate directories, as suggested and on a Windows Server 2012 VM in Azure

**Edit**

Here is are the links([1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102487348/logsfForStackQuestion/neo4j1/messages.log), [2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102487348/logsfForStackQuestion/neo4j1/neo4j.0.0.log), [3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102487348/logsfForStackQuestion/neo4j2/messages.log), [4](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102487348/logsfForStackQuestion/neo4j2/neo4j.0.0.log)) to the shared log files as asked for in the comments, 1 and 2 are for intance1, 3 and 4 are for instance2.

Comment: Can you share the logs from your 3 databases? `data\log\*` and `data\graph.db\messages.log`.

Comment: @MichaelHunger i have added links to the log files. link one and three are the two instances `message.log` and two and four are `neo4j.0.0`